# How to set primary port in ModemManager?

Tags: linux, modem

I have a pretty old and pretty buggy modem.
The QMI interface does not work reliably, so i want to use ttyUSB2 (at) instead.
Is there a way to tell ModemManager to use that?

Also is there a way to tell it to only use it IF the model number is MC7304?

One possible solution is to blacklist `cdc_wdm`, but i have not found a way to blacklist conditionally (based on modem model number).

```
jsaak@olimex:~$ mmcli -m 4
  --------------------------------
  General  |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/4
           |            device id: 8e164736c3b567f4afa63d2fa8c7c88cda14fb80
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
           |                model: MC7304
           |    firmware revision: SWI9X15C_05.05.16.02 r21040 carmd-fwbuild1 2014/03/17 23:49:48
           |         h/w revision: 1.0
           |            supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |              current: gsm-umts, lte
           |         equipment id: 356853050783713
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/platform/soc/1c1c000.usb/usb2/2-1
           |              drivers: qmi_wwan, qcserial
           |               plugin: sierra
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm1
           |                ports: cdc-wdm0 (qmi), cdc-wdm1 (qmi), ttyUSB0 (qcdm), 
           |                       ttyUSB2 (at), wwan0 (net), wwan1 (net)
```